# BuildContext: the meaning of nearest enclosing?

Tags: flutter

I'm reading the docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html

> This can lead to some tricky cases. For example, Theme.of(context) looks for the nearest *enclosing* Theme of the given build context. ...

Does *enclosing* includes the Theme of current context? I don't understand what the tricky cases the author indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky situation they mentioned becomes more clear if you understand the previous statement:

> In particular, this means that within a build method, the build context of the widget of the build method is not the same as the build context of the widgets returned by that build method.

Ok, not a very helpful language. Imagine:

FooWidgetA:
attributes: context, height, width
methods: build

FooWidgetB:
attributes: context, theme
methods: build

FooWidgetB gets built inside FooWidgetA `build` method. If you try to find `theme` using the `context` of `FooWidgetA` it won't find because `FooWidgetA` is one level above in the widget tree.

So, exemplifying their tricky situation, it looks like this:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext buildMethodContext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Here we create the [ThemeData] that our method below will try to find
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orange),
      builder: (BuildContext materialAppContext, _) {
        return RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Get ThemeData'),
          onPressed: () {
            getThemeData(buildMethodContext);  // unsucessful
            getThemeData(materialAppContext);  // sucessful
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  ThemeData getThemeData(BuildContext context) => Theme.of(context);
}
```

It's tricky because, since the two contexts are way to close, it's easy to forget that `buildMethodContext` is actually from the parent (`Foo`), so it cannot see `materialAppContext`.

Comment: I don't know which things in Flutter can have `BuildContext`. 1. why it's called `buildMethodContext` not `fooContext`? 2. then why it's called `materialAppContext` not `buildMethodContext`? (In my current understanding `builder: ` accepts a anonymous `build()` function, not sure whether this is correct.)

Comment: `buildMethodContext` could have been named as `fooContext`. `materialAppContext` cannot be named as `buildMethodContext` because the `builder` we pass as parameter is not going to replace `MaterialApp`'s builder. It'll be called somewhere at `MaterialApp`'s builder, but it is not the builder itself.

Comment: `I don't know which things in Flutter can have BuildContext` > Widgets have `BuildContext`. This context is the one given to the method `build`. That's why  they are called `BuildContext`.

Comment: Nope. As I said, the anonymous method you pass is going to be executed somewhere at the `MaterialApp's` build method, but it does not replace the build method.

Comment: I feel like we got in another point. Did you understand the answer I gave you to your actual question?

Comment: So it works like `MaterialApp#build(materialAppContext) { /*...*/ builder(materialAppContext); /*...*/ }`?

Comment: `So from your answer, my question Does enclosing includes the Theme of current context? should be yes?` > Yes.
`So it works like...` > Pretty much like it. It actually wraps the `build` method we pass inside a `Builder`, just like you did in your answer. Take a look (note that `widget.build` refers to the `build` method we passed): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L470

Comment: "It actually wraps _the build method_ we pass inside a Builder" you mean the `builder: ` one, so it's not `builder(context) { MaterialApp#build(context) }`?(This is the last clarification, since my English not very well...) Btw thank you so much I think now I understand it.

Comment: I did look, but I don't understand `Builder()`, so it's basically something has `build(context)`?

Comment: From your snippet and the link, if `Builder` class itself is a widget(so it has its own context), then conceptually in your answer it's actually not `materialAppContext` right?

Comment: Since `Builder` looks like a widget contains nothing like `Theme` etc, it works like `materialAppContext` is passed to `builder: `, correct?

Comment: That's correct. Honestly, I didn't even know there was a `Builder` in the middle of all of this when I answered you, but since it doesn't make any difference using `materialAppContext` or `builderContext` in this case, I would not tell you (if I knew) to make things more simple.

Comment: thank you so much, I think this is the most difficult part of flutter. while not necessary, could you update your answer with these comments(then we can delete them)?